# For loop in a dictionary with nested list

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, nested-lists

I want to replace efficiently some values in some variables (question_16_a, question16_b and question 16_c), I create a dictionary with the name of the question as key and a nested list as values, the first list in the nested list are the values I want to replace and the second list contains the values I want as replacement.

```
 dict_1={"question_16_a":[["Un assemblage de cépages","Ugni blanc","UNIBLANC","ugni blanc","uni-blanc","Petit Manseng","Rolle","Chenin"],["blend_of_grape_varieties","Ugni-blanc","Ugni-blanc","Ugni-blanc","Ugni-blanc","Other","Other","Other"]],"question_16_b":[["CHASSELAS","Chasselas / Pinot Gris"],["Chasselas","Chasselas"]],"question_16_c":[["MUSCADELLE","muscadelle","Muller Thurgau","Xinisteri indigenous grape variery","vERMENTINO","pinot noir"],["Muscadelle","Muscadelle","Other","Other","Other","Other"]],"question_16_d":[["MUSCADELLE","Rousanne"],["Muscadelle","Other"]]}
```

I did this for loop, but it does not work

```
for keys,value in dict_1:
            df1[keys]=df1[keys].replace(value[0],value[1])
```

I have this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally came out with this, I think it works well.
I separate the dict_1 in dict_1 and dict_2, now the lists in dict_1 are the values I want to replace. And the lists in dict_2 are the values to replace with.

```
 dict_1={"question_16_a":["Un assemblage de cépages","Ugni blanc","UNIBLANC","ugni blanc","uni-blanc","Petit Manseng","Rolle","Chenin"],"question_16_b":["CHASSELAS","Chasselas / Pinot Gris"],"question_16_c":["MUSCADELLE","muscadelle","Muller Thurgau","Xinisteri indigenous grape variery","vERMENTINO","pinot noir"],"question_16_d":["MUSCADELLE","Rousanne"]}

dict_2={"question16_a":["blend_of_grape_varieties","Ugni-blanc","Ugni-blanc","Ugni-blanc","Ugni-blanc","Other","Other","Other"],"question_16_b":["Chasselas","Chasselas"],"question_16_c":["Muscadelle","Muscadelle","Other","Other","Other","Other"],"question_16_d":["Muscadelle","Other"]}

for (k,v),(k2,v2) in zip(dict_1.items(),dict_2.items()):
    df1[k]=df1[k].replace(v,v2)
```